# How to vary the supply voltage for Xilinx Virtex-5 FPGA ML501, ML506, and ML510 boards?

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx, virtex

I'm trying to do an experiment to see how different supply voltages affect the frequency of ring oscillator and the reliability of SRAM cells. I have access to a couple of Xilinx Virtex-5 boards, namely, ML501, ML506, and ML510. I have tried to search the web, but so far I haven't found anything useful. I have some experiences with FPGA design, but I have never tried to change the supply voltage before. So I'm really clueless on how to start. Can someone (who have done similar projects) please tell me how to vary the supply voltage of those FPGA boards?

Comment: You might try this question over at the electronics stack exchange. Power supplies and voltages might be a bit beyond the scope of this programming site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can easily change the power on those boards. They are using small power bricks with pre-defined power, so it will not be an easy task to change them, unless if you remove them and replace them with external power.

But, you have to be careful, you must make sure that all the power is stable and correct before the FPGA is loaded, otherwise you may damage your (expensive) FPGAs.